# How to Remove the last char of String in C#?

Tags: c#, string, trim

I have a numeric string, which may be `"124322"` or `"1231.232"` or `"132123.00"`.
I want to remove the last char of my string (whatever it is).
So I want if my string is `"99234"` became `"9923"`.

The length of string is variable. It's not constant so I can not use string.Remove or trim or some like them(I Think).

How do I achieve this?

Comment: `Please Read this carefully And then tell me this question is duplicate` [This is a duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3573284/trim-last-character-from-a-string)

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2776673/how-do-i-truncate-a-net-string

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Delete last char of string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7901360/delete-last-char-of-string)

Answer (score 83, accepted):

```
YourString = YourString.Remove(YourString.Length - 1);
```

Comment: The important point here is that we need to assign it back to the original string. I lost time because I did not notice it, so maybe helpful to someone else.

Answer (score 14):

```
var input = "12342";
var output = input.Substring(0, input.Length - 1);
```

or

```
var output = input.Remove(input.Length - 1);
```

Answer (score 4):

`newString = yourString.Substring(0, yourString.length -1);`

Answer (score 2):

If this is something you need to do a lot in your application, or you need to chain different calls, you can create an extension method:

```
public static String TrimEnd(this String str, int count)
{
    return str.Substring(0, str.Length - count);
}
```

and call it:

```
string oldString = "...Hello!";
string newString = oldString.TrimEnd(1); //returns "...Hello"
```

or chained:

```
string newString = oldString.Substring(3).TrimEnd(1);  //returns "Hello"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `string` datatype, below code works:

```
string str = str.Remove(str.Length - 1);
```

---

But when you have **`StringBuilder`**, you have to specify second parameter `length` as well.

### [image: SB]

That is,

```
string newStr = sb.Remove(sb.Length - 1, 1).ToString();
```

> To avoid below error:

[image: SB2]

Answer (score 0):

`string testString = "some string"; testString = testString.TrimEnd(testString.Last());`
It will remove the last char from the string